# Как загрузить картинку по ссылке?

Tags: php, yii2

Можно ли организовать загрузку картинки со стороннего сайта по ссылке на картинку к примеру http://www.nokiaplanet.com/uploads/posts/2015-11/1448881894_cute-kitty-360x640.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$remote_path = 'http://www.nokiaplanet.com/uploads/posts/2015-11/1448881894_cute-kitty-360x640.jpg';
$local_path = 'image.jpg';

$image = file_get_contents($remote_path);
if ($image)
{
    file_put_contents($local_path, $image);
}
```